# task manager user id using C#

Tags: c#, taskmanager

[image: I am looking to get remote user id using]

Please, refer image for getting id of the user. I searched over internet but could not get the answer. Below is my finding but still this id is not coming.

```
if (OS.ToUpper().Contains("WINDOWS 10"))
{
      Process[] localByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("System");
      pid = localByName[0].Id.ToString();
}
else if (OS.ToUpper().Contains("WINDOWS 7"))
{
      pid = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().SessionId.ToString();
}
```

Comment: psexec \\remoteSystem -u username -p password -h -i 2(want to fetch this user id dynamically) -d
"path\Test.exe"

Answer (score 0):

use cassia for get user session id.

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
            using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer(machineName))
            {
                server.Open();
                foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(session.UserName))
                        continue;
                    if (session.UserName.Equals(userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        sessionId = session.SessionId;
                }
            }
```

try this.

Comment: I'm getting access is denied error at server.GetSessions. Do we required to provide username and password? if required than how?

Comment: Thank you so much it works. But before adding this code need to change in the registry. AllowRemoteRPC value set to be 1.